# Stream Audio or Music File from a Windows Azure Cloud URL

Tags: php, azure, streaming

Is there any sample or open source application to stream audio files from a Windows Azure Cloud URL for eg. https://portalvhdsjqlyq1x0819tb.blob.core.windows.net/songs/Sleep%20Away.mp3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob storage does not support streaming protocol. There is [Windows Azure Media Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/) which is GA and which supports streaming. Read more on [how to use Media Services here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/).

There is some workaround, described more than two years ago from Steve Marx [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/smooth-streaming-with-windows-azure-blobs-and-cdn), [here](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/publishing-adaptive-streaming-video-from-expression-encoder-to-windows-azure-blobs) and [here](https://github.com/smarx/WazSmoothStreamingPlayer).

However, I would suggest exploring the Media Services if streaming is required. If streaming is not explicitly required, progressive download is already supported from Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the  WazSmoothStreamingPlayer comes up with an error after running the application. since I am a php developer can the same be achieved with a php application?

Comment: You have to explicitly state in the question that you are working with PHP. Unfortunately Media Services currently has only PHP SDK, but it exposes a [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973617.aspx), which can be consumed from  any language/platform understanding the REST protocol. As for the samples - I never actually used them, because I am using Media Services.

Comment: I meant that Media Services has only .NET SDK, sorry for confusion in previous comment!

Comment: Thankyou astaykov for the help. I'll check the REST API with PHP.

Comment: Just for a hint - it uses OAuth for authentication. You will have to get an OAuth token from ACS to present it to the Media Services API. Not sure whether this is well documented. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh973616.aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: The application at the link: https://github.com/smarx/WazSmoothStreamingPlayer returns an error while running the code. Is there any other .NET application available? I prefer PHP but .NET apps should be fine too.

Comment: There is one full blown Windows Azure Media Service demo app [here](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb), which is deployed live and can be tested [here](http://wamediaweb.azurewebsites.net/InitMedia/). It also has embedded Smooth Streaming Player for the Smooth Streaming sources. Take a look at the readme and code comments.

Comment: Sure I will try this. I was trying to stream the blob using php application by following tutorial and have the code: 
require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;
$connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=portalvhdsjqlyq1x0819tb;AccountKey=XXXXXXXXXX";
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
$blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob("songs", "Sleep%20Away.mp3");
fpassthru($blob->getContentStream());
but it gives the error Unable to access vendor\autoload.php

Comment: would you update your question with the code. It is  hard to read in comments, plus having updated question may help others tune in with ideas.

Comment: require_once 'vendor\autoload.php';                                   use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;                               use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;                 $connectionString =   "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ihjkhk;AccountKey=X‌​XXXXXXXXX";                                                      $blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()-createBlobService($connectionString);                                 $blob = $blobRestProxy->getBlob("songs","Sleep%20Away.mp3"); fpassthru($blob->getContentStream());Unable2access vendor\autoload.php

Comment: The above code gives an error Unable to access vendor\autoload.php. I was unable to paste the code in fully with indentation due to limitation on number of characters.

Comment: Check out the Official PHP tutorial [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/blob-service/). There no such `vendor\autoload.php`. This is probably some third party autoloader, which has to be referenced from the article you've read.

Comment: Also Fatal error: Class 'pear\WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder' not found error comes up after execution. I can see a ServicesBuilder.php file under this path.